# 3D CharacterController ride moving platforms in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physx

I have a **player controller script** that I'm writing that **uses the `CharacterController` component** to move around and handle collisions. I've been able to implement basically every feature that I want **except for moving platforms**.

**Some things to note:**

-For testing purposes, the **platform moves via the `Update()` function and does not have a `Rigidbody` component** attached to it. I don't think that rigidbodies would make a difference in the first place, but I could be wrong.

-Currently, when my player stands on the platform, it *kind of* does what it's supposed to do, but **it moves with a large amount of jitter.** In other words, the player isn't able to depenetrate itself as fast as the platform moves, therefore causing the jitter.

**Here's what I've tried:**

My initial thought was to create a **script on the moving platform that keeps track of its own velocity.** Then, on the player's `OnControllerColliderHit(...)` function, I would get the platform's velocity and add it to the player's velocity. **This caused the same jittery effect as before.**

My next idea was to **parent the player to the platform** whenever the player collided with it. This solution also did not work because **apparently `CharacterController`s do NOT like it when they are a child of a moving object.** The platform's transformations had little to no effect on the player, regardless of its speed. So once again, **the jitteriness continued.**

Just to test out possible solutions, I also tried combining the two previous fixes and still, the jitteriness lives among us.

**Closing thoughts:**

I'm beginning to think that it's not entirely possible, but I'm still holding out hope. I would also prefer to not to purchase an existing asset or switch to a `Rigidbody` component because neither would fit the style of my game.

Feel free to ask questions for more details and thank you in advance!

****EDIT****
**THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN MOVED TO GAMEDEV.STACKEXCHANGE.COM**